# Windows Service with web interface .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, api, webservicehost

I need to develop a windows service that will do some basic task a few times a day, nothing heavy. As part of the requirements it needs a web interface so it can be configured from a browser.

Example:

> Mr Engineer opens up his browser and enters `localhost:1234/Config`. A
>   simple html web page is returned that allows him to enter some values
>   and post them to the server. The windows service will then use these
>   new values.

What I currently have is two different ways of doing this. The first is just by creating a WebServiceHost in my ServiceBase like so:

```
// Provide the base address.
serviceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));

// Open the ServiceHostBase 
serviceHost.Open();
```

I then create an IService and specify an operation like so:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet]
Stream Get();
```

And finally implement the interface like so:

```
public Stream Get()
{
    UriTemplateMatch uriInfo = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch;
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html";

    MemoryStream rawResponse = new MemoryStream();
    TextWriter response = new StreamWriter(rawResponse, Encoding.UTF8);
    response.Write("<h1>test</h1>");
    response.Flush();

    rawResponse.Position = 0;
    return rawResponse;
}
```

This works **FINE**. I am able to query the web service from my browser and I get the desired result.

However, I have recently stumbled across WebApi and have been able to replicate equal success by doing the following:

```
HttpSelfHostConfiguration config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(new Uri("http://localhost:50231/"));

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

// Create server
var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);

// Start listening
server.OpenAsync().Wait();
```

And then by having a controller like so:

```
public class HelloController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Content = new StringContent("<html><body>Hello World</body></html>");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
        return response;
    }
}
```

So, these are the two methods I've come up with to meet the requirements. Which of these is considered better? Or are they both terrible and is there a better way?

Comment: I don't think there's a bad or good way. Depends on your requirements. WebAPI may be a bit overkill if it's something simple, but it allows you to scale with different clients in the future. Like say for example you may decide to use mobile app instead of web browser you can leverage off your WebAPI.

Comment: As interesting as this question is, the answer is entirely opinion-based and therefore [off-topic on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I am not voting to close, but I suggest you try to reword the question to conform to the site's guidelines before it is.